# Want layered navigation filters on top in one column layout

Tags: category, layered-navigation, ce-1.9.0.1

I am having a issue.
I want to filter the products using the attributes on the top.
for eg., I want to filter the product by type. Type is a name of attribute.
for reference the site is http://www.loft-interiors.co.uk/beds-and-mattresses/bed-frames/upholstered-beds 
I want navigation like this and my current site is 
http://infigic.com/landlordstore/furniture/living-room/sofa-armchairs/three-seat-sofa.html 
Please suggest a way

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to move the navigation block fron the left side to the top and then adjust the styling.

Open `app\design\frontend\<PACKAGE>\<THEME>\layout\catalog.xml`,  find

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

replace with

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="product_list" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Then modify the vertical layout to horizontal wit CSS.

Comment: Be aware - some newer js and 3rd party extensions expect that it be located logically in the DOM in the class `col-left` or `col-left-first`